# Returning variable from a different environment

Tags: mit-scheme

I'm attempting to return a variable in the scope of a different environment.
What I have currently is

```
(define make-empty-env
   (lambda()
      (make-top-level-environment)
   )
)
```

which creates a new environment when you call it from the interpreter
i.e. (define env (make-empty-env))

If I define the variable "a" as 15 in "env", my goal is to return this value through a function called from the user-initial-environment.

Something along the lines of

(apply-env env 'v) outputs -> value of variable v in scope of env. 
v can be undefined in user-initial-environment but would still return a value if the variable exists in env.

I've tried:

```
(define apply-env
   (lambda (env v)
       (eval (+ v 0) env)
   )
)
```

which doesn't work since I'm passing a symbol 'v when I call the function. My main problem is that I don't know how to pass a symbol and treat it like a variable in the function. This is for a homework and the prompt for the function is:

> (apply-env env v)
>
> Returns the value of variable v in environment env.
>
> Here are some calls to apply-env:
>
> In test-env, a = 1, b = 2
>
> (apply-env test-env 'a)
>   1
>
> (apply-env test-env 'b)
>   2

I'm relatively new to scheme so I'm probably missing some fundamental basics, any pointers or help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the design implementation for your environment variable is up to you. Since its a homework question I'm assuming that you can go about it any way you like (I assume).

So lets say you want to make your environment variable as a that is a list of list of 2 elements.

```
env -> ((var1,val1),(var2,val2),......,(varn.valn))

E.g.

env -> ((a,1),(b,2),(c,3))
```

Now when you want to "create" your environment initially, you simply want to call a function which returns the initial environment which is **empty**. Now our environment variable `env` is just an empty list `'()`. You could make a function like this

```lisp
(define (make-empty-env)
    (lambda ()
        '()
    )
)
```

Now to add, remove and update variables in `env` you can implement function like `car` and `cdr` and `in-env?` for the underlying data structure

```lisp
;;; cdr like function for env
(define (cdr-env env)
    (cdr env)
)

;;; car like function for env
(define (car-env)
    (list (car env))
)

;;; Returns boolean for v in env
(define (in-env? env)
    (cond
        ((null? env)    ; If env is empty then v doesnt exist in env
            #f
        )
        ((equal? v (car (car env))) ; If first element of the first list in env matches with v 
            #t
        )
        (else       ; Recursive step to find if v is in the remaining enviornment env
            (in-env? v (cdr env))
        )
    )
)
```

Using these functions you can relatively easily implement your insertion, retrieval and updation functions for `env`.

```lisp
;;; Update the value variable v to val in env. This function assumes that you are calling it in the insert-env function
(define (update-env v val env)
    (cond 
        ((null? env)
            '()
        )
        ((equal? v (car (car env)))
            (append (cdr env) (list (list v val)))
        )
        (else
            (append 
                (update-env v val (cdr env)) 
                (list (list (car (car env)) (car (cdr (car env)))))
            )
        )
    )
)


;;; add a variable-value pair (v,val) to env, also checks if variable already exists in pair. If so then updates it
(define (insert-env v val env)
    (cond 
        ((in-env? v env)
            (update-env v val env)
        )
        (else  ; Add to env the 2 element list (v val)
            (append env (list (list v val)))
        )
    )
)

;;; Gets the value of variable v or returns an error message
(define apply-env
    (lambda (env v)
        (cond 
            ((null? env)    ; If env is empty then no variablles exist for the name v
                (error "appply-env: found empty enviroment")
            )
            ((equal? (car (car env)) v) ; First element of the first list is v [matching var found in env]
                (car (cdr (car env))) ; Second element of that list is value of v
            )
            (else       ; Else look for v in the rest of the env list
                (apply-env (cdr env) v) 
            )
        )
    )
)
```

> NOTE: 
>   Your implementations of functions like above for `env` will depend on how you choose to implement the data structure that will store your variable bindings in `env`
>   You can use any data structure you like. E.g. Binary tree. stack, queue, etc

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the addition isn't staged. Consider the following using quasiquotiation:

```
(define apply-env
   (lambda (env v)
       (eval `(+ ,v 0) env)
   )
)
```

The quasiquotation is equivalent to `(list '+ v 0)`.